# Gnome-Tweaks is missing the Application Dropdown

Tags: 22.04, gnome-tweaks

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I installed gnome-tweaks but I do not see the Application Options.

[image]

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate what it is you are expecting to do with `Applications`. GNOME 42 is a different animal to GNOME 3 but there is an option for `Legacy Applications` instead. It is the difference between the X11 and wayland windowing system.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome 42 adopted a new version of its graphical toolkit, GTK4 with its `libadwaita` library. GTK2 and GTK3 themes do not work with GTK4.

Because of this move, applications that "still" use GTK3 (currently still a vast majority, including even Files 42.0) and even GTK2 (The Gimp still does) are now considered - and labeled as - **Legacy applications**.

Comment: Thank you for the information!

Comment: If this answers your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the question. That also shows other users that a useful answer can be found here.